# Issue loading model data from YAML file

Tags: java, playframework, yaml

I'm attempting to load a model from a yaml file. The contents are:

```
  #test data

   User(marchaos):
       username:     marchaos
       email:        marchaos@email.com
       passwordHash: cf6dd541822b1b3d2d23c92adda75211
```

The model looks like this.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model
{
    @Unique
    @Required
    private final String username;

    @Email
    @Required
    private final String email;

    @Required
    private final String passwordHash;

    public User(String username, String email, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
            //TODO: salt
        this.passwordHash = Codec.hexMD5(password);
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
}
```

The YAML file is loaded in a Bootstrap class:

```
Fixtures.loadModels("User.yml");
```

The user looks like it gets created, but all of the fields are null:

```
System.out.println(((User) User.all().first()).getUsername());
// prints null
```

Any idea why there would be no data for the user? If I create the user using the constructor, the user data exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you **only use spaces** and **no tabs** in your yaml file.

you also need to have **a public no arguments constructor**. 
the **properties are not allowed to be final** and if you make them private, you'll have to provide a setter for them.

on a side note: you shouldn't hash your passwords with md5. its a security risk (rainbowtables)

Comment: I'm aware of the md5 issue (hence the salt comment). I get an error when I use tabs, so it's not that. Any other ideas what it could be ?

Comment: Worked like a charm after setting my password field to private, then yaml had to use the setter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that your User properties are marked as final and private. From [play documentation](http://www2.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/model#properties) you can read:

> The convention is that any public, non static, non final field of a
>   class is seen as a property.

Comment: That was it. I think the documentation could be a little clearer.

Comment: The play documentation link is broken.